# \href italic font for external links

Tags: hyperref, luatex, italic

I'm trying to make a document (using `lualatex`) with internal and external links, using the `xcolor` and `hyperref` packages. I want my link setup like this:

- no boxes around links (underlined in a defined color would be ok)
- internal links: normal font
- external links: blue color, italic font

From others here on stackexchange, I thought it should work like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % hyperfootnotes=false
    \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=, linkcolor=, urlcolor=blue}
    \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily\itshape} % I thought this should make it italic, but it does not
    \newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=#1}}

\begin{document}
    Here is some basic url: \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}.
    But why is my link not \textit{italic}?
\end{document}
```

I guess there is something very basic I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\UrlFont` is for urls, but you have here a "simple" href text, for this only the urlcolor applies. Use either `\url` or in the \href  `\nolinkurl`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % 
    \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=, linkcolor=, urlcolor=blue}
    \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily\itshape} % I thought this should make it italic, but it does not
    \newcommand{\changeurlcolor}[1]{\hypersetup{urlcolor=#1}}

\begin{document}
    Here is some basic url: 
    \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}.

    \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}{\nolinkurl{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions}}.
    But why is my link not \textit{italic}?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works, I see the point, thanks. How could I potentially `\renewcommand` the `\href` definition to always act like this? Tried `\renewcommand{\href}{\href{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}}`, but this is obiously wrong.

Comment: Hmm... maybe `\let\hreforig=\href \renewcommand{\href}{\hreforig{#1}{\nolinkurl{#2}}}`? But I didn't test it... it works only if `\href` is a very simple definition. I wouldn't do that, better stick with your own macro name...