# hyperref specifying styles for certain types of links

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Using the `hyperref` package, I want to have my cross-reference links (tables, figures, sections) to be formatted in small-caps. I'm aware of the `frenchlinks` option, but that turns every link into small caps. I would much prefer to still have normal URL-links e.g and only the cross-references are formatted in small-caps, just like it's possibly to have different colors for different types of links.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:section}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Figure}
    \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

Text. \autoref{sec:section}

Some more Text. \autoref{fig:figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can revert the font for url links \renewcommand\UrlFont{\normalfont}, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528152/2388

Comment: there is also `\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}`.